# I need to extend an array

Tags: php, arrays

I got an array which I filled initially with date and amount=0. 
This amount must be shared to a number of people.
These people I want to add as additional array fields, so that I get:
date | amount | user-1 | user-2 |....| user-n

From another array ($user) I got all user-1 ... user-n

```
// Startday   October 12 2014
// Endday     February 28 2015
$sd = 'October 12 2014';
$ed = 'February 28 2015';

$period = new \DatePeriod(
    \DateTime::createFromFormat('F d Y', $sd),
    new \DateInterval('P1D'), 
    \DateTime::createFromFormat('F d Y', $ed)->modify('+1 day'));

foreach($period as $date) {
  $dd = $date->format('F j, Y');
  $pay_day[] = array($dd, 0);
      for ($b=1;$b<$amount_users;$b++) {
          array_push($pay_day[$line],0);
      }
}
```

I don't know $line. It should be the current one from $pay_day[]

Answer (score 0):

I worked around in this way:

```
// Startday   October 12 2014
// Endday     February 28 2015
$sd = 'October 12 2014';
$ed = 'February 28 2015';

$period = new \DatePeriod(
    \DateTime::createFromFormat('F d Y', $sd),
    new \DateInterval('P1D'), 
    \DateTime::createFromFormat('F d Y', $ed)->modify('+1 day'));

$line=0;

foreach($period as $date) {
  $dd = $date->format('F j, Y');
  $pay_day[$line] = array($dd, 0);
      for ($b=1;$b<$amount_users;$b++) {
          array_push($pay_day[$line],0);
      }
}
```